# Is there a way to invoke manually Spring Quartz Job from Linux Shell

Tags: java, linux, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a spring project with an archiver job, I want sometimes to invoke it manually from command line, is there an option?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="archiverService" class="jobs.service.ArchiverService" />

<bean id="myJob" class="jobs.MyJobs" />

<bean id="archiverJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="cmd.jobs.Archiver" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="myJob" value-ref="myJob" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="cronTriggerArchiverJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="archiverJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 23 * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="archiverJob" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTriggerArchiverJob" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

In [Quart Examples Page](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples) you will find `Linux.sh` **AND** `Windows.bat` examples like [EXAMPLE1](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example1). 
**Just replace your JDK installation root.**

Basically:

```
$JAVA -classpath $QUARTZ_CP $LOGGING_PROPS org.quartz.examples.example1.SimpleExample
```

**example1.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
# Change this to your JDK installation root
#
#JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18

JRE=$JAVA_HOME/jre
JAVA=$JRE/bin/java

workdir=`dirname $0`
workdir=`cd ${workdir} && pwd`
QUARTZ=${workdir}/../..

. ${QUARTZ}/examples/bin/buildcp.sh

if [ `uname | grep CYGWIN` ]; then
  workdir=`cygpath -w -p $workdir`
fi

LOGGING_PROPS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:${workdir}/log4j.xml"

$JAVA -classpath $QUARTZ_CP $LOGGING_PROPS org.quartz.examples.example1.SimpleExample
```